# How can we insert date into the SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For each data insert in SQLite database, I would like to get insert the `current Date` as well. How can I do it in Xamarin Forms app ?

Below is my code which now insert some status data into the database.

```
public void OnOKButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            overlay.IsVisible = false;
            DisplayAlert("Result",
                          string.Format("You entered {0}", EnteredStatus.Text), "OK");
            SoccerAvailability soccerAvailability = new SoccerAvailability();
            soccerAvailability.SoccerStatus = EnteredStatus.Text;

            var dailySoccerStatus = EnteredStatus.Text;
           int x = 0;
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EnteredStatus.Text))
                {
                    //Insert the soccer status to the database:
                    x = conn.Insert(soccerAvailability);
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Soccer Availability", "Availability cannot be left blank", "OK");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            if (x == 1)
            {

                Navigation.PushAsync(new Settings(soccerAvailability));
            }

            DisplaySoccerStatus();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a `CurrentDate` `DateTime` property on your `SoccerAvailability` model

```
soccerAvailability.CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
x = conn.Insert(soccerAvailability);
```